# how do I resize HTML onclick? how would I make two onclick functions next to each other?

Tags: html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
```

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    p {

        background-color:powderblue;
    }
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 0 4px;
}

.column {
    padding: 0 4px;
    flex: 20%;
}
```

I'm not sure if this is actually doing anything

```
.onclick{
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}



</style>
<body>
```

I want these two onclicks to be next to each other

```
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <p id="demo" onclick="myFunction1()">Click me.</p>
    </tr>
    </tr>
        <p id="funct" onclick="myFunction2()">Click me.</p>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This part details what the functions do

```
<script>
    function myFunction1() {
        if (document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML == "Click me."){
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "YOU CLICKED ME!";
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Click me.";
        }
    }
    function myFunction2() {
        if (document.getElementById("funct").innerHTML == "Click me."){
            document.getElementById("funct").innerHTML = "YOU CLICKED ME!";
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("funct").innerHTML = "Click me.";
        }
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean with *next to each other*? What part of the behaviour you are currently experiencing is not good for you?

Comment: 1) The second row of your table has an error in the opening tag. 2) `.onclick ` class definition won't work as you expect.

Comment: @Cubo78 I want them on the same line

Comment: @Cubo78 I fixed the table but no change

Answer (score 0):

You see your paragraphs in the different rows because you placed them in different rows of your table.

Just change into

```
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p id="demo" onclick="myFunction1()">Click me.</p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p id="funct" onclick="myFunction2()">Click me.</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and they will be placed in the same row.

In HTML tables:

- `<tr>` tag starts a new row
- `</tr>` tag ends current row
- `<td>` tag starts a new box in current row
- `</td>` tag ends current box in current row

Anyway, though it's not the object of the current question, I suggest you finding a different way than tables for organizing your web page. Take a look to `<div>`s + CSS.